# "Scrambler" functions? Like random number generators

Tags: math, random, numbers

I am interested in a modification of the usual idea of random number generators.  That is, typical generators generate long strings of reasonably independent, uniformly distributed numbers from that space.  This is intended to be used with one seed, repeatedly.

However, for my purpose, I want a way of generating a "random number" from another number (actually from a grid of integers) in a way that is "independent," in the sense that knowing the outputs for nearby points don't help you predict the value at your point.

In practice, using traditional random number generators works reasonably well, but I'd be interested in any work that was actually done for this purpose.

Comment: are you asking for this?
[cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator)

Comment: Not obviously.  Security is not that important for my application, and as I mentioned in the post, PRNGs often care more about the independence of a sequence of generated numbers from a single seed than about the independence of the first generated number from the seed itself.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

> The ideal cryptographic hash function has four main properties:
>
> 1. it is easy to compute the hash value for any given message
> 2. it is infeasible to generate a message that has a given hash
> 3. it is infeasible to modify a message without changing the hash
> 4. it is infeasible to find two different messages with the same hash

Some commonly used hash functions are [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) and [SHA-512](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-512). One called [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is still being used even though it has been shown to be insecure.

Comment: This sounds promising.  But actually I need one more property (which is related to (2), but not actually implied), which is that given a "graph" of this hash function, no obvious patterns will arise.  So for example, if I am hashing integers by XORing them with another (secret) integer, that probably suits the above properties, but if I switch the LSB of my input, it will only switch the LSB of the output.  So it is "too continuous" and it doesn't work for my purposes.

Comment: Leaving my comment above, but realizing it may not be completely correct.  If we require that the algorithm be well-known, the XOR wouldn't satisfy (2), and in fact continuity would be a barrier to (2) as well (if you get close, you just jitter your input around a bit and approach the desired hash).

Comment: A well constructed hash function will also have the property that changing one bit in the input changes half of the bits in the output.